# OAuth, javascript and many URI's

Tags: javascript, oauth

I'm trying to make a program that can be hosted by many peoples, like an app.
The app use a REST API, so I must authenticate with Oauth,
and because anyone should be able to host the program, the redirect URI cannot be static.

Further, I don't want to use any server-side processing, which means only javascript for me.

Is it even possible to make a secure and working solution with non-static redirect URI,
and only using javascript, to work in a normal webbrowser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you use the information provided in the request to your app to indicate the URL for your app. For instance, if the request came to `http://example.com/path/to/app` and you knew in your app that `/to/app` was part of your routing infrastructure, then the path to your app is `http://example.com/path/`.

That is how I would determine it, using a serverside language.

Using a javascript library, which would be loaded from the server, I would either determine it like the above, or I would just hard code it on the generation of the javascript file (when you tell people where to download the javascript, it can use a form that requires their web address first).

Comment: I don't want to use anything server-side.
And is javascript even possible to use, considering the keys would be accessible to anyone?

Comment: So, I gave a non-server-side solution, but thanks for reading my answer only half-way.

Comment: Sorry, I accidently pressed enter before I was finished typing. I was meaning to add:
is javascript even possible to use, considering the keys would be accessible to anyone?

Comment: That is a matter of what you would like to do. Anytime you process in javascript you expose the keys to the end-user at some point. That is a distinction only you can make.